# Array subscript out of range at line Error in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I am trying to create new set of variables using arrays. but i am getting this error "
ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 581 column 23."

in my program i have set of macro variables n1 to n15
Here is my code i can;t find out how does my arrays goes out of range since all arrays have 15 elements

```
data allsae1; 
*length _a1 _a2 _a3 _a4 _a5 _a6 _a7 _a8 _a9 _a10 _a11 _a12 _a13 _a14 _a99 _b1 _b2 _b3 _b4 _b5 _b6 _b7 _b8 _b9 _b10 _b11 _b12 _b13 _b14 _b99 $10;
set  allsae; 

array _anum{15} a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a99;
array _bnum{15} b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 b10 b11 b12 b13 b14 b99;
array astat{15} _a1 _a2 _a3 _a4 _a5 _a6 _a7 _a8 _a9 _a10 _a11 _a12 _a13 _a14 _a99;
array bstat{15} _b1 _b2 _b3 _b4 _b5 _b6 _b7 _b8 _b9 _b10 _b11 _b12 _b13 _b14 _b99;

%macro stats;

%do i=1 %to 15;
    %if _anum[i] !=. %then %do;
    astat[i]=strip(put(_anum[i], best.))||" ("||strip(put(_anum[i]/(&&n&i) *100, 8.1))||"%)";
    %end;

    bstat[i] = strip(put(_bnum[i], best.));
%end;
%mend stats;
%stats;
run;
```

Comment: What are the macro variables N1, N2, ... N15?  Where are they defined? What do they have in them?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have macro code here?  I don't see any place where you need to generate SAS code.  The only place is the reference to `&&n&i` but I don't see where you have defined any macro variables named N1, N2, etc.

The string `_anum[i]` is always not equal to the string `.` so you always generate the SAS statement

```
astat[i]=strip(put(_anum[i], best.))||" ("||strip(put(_anum[i]/(<something>) *100, 8.1))||"%)";
```

But you never created the variable `I` so the index into `astat` and `_anum` arrays will be invalid.

Most likely you just want a normal DO loop and don't need to define a macro at all.  If you really have those 15 macro variables and they contain numeric strings you might just use the SYMGETN() function.

```
do i=1 to 15;
  if not missing(_anum[i]) then do;
    astat[i]=strip(put(_anum[i], best.))||" ("||strip(put(_anum[i]/(symgetn(cats('n',i))) *100, 8.1))||"%)";
  end;
  bstat[i] = strip(put(_bnum[i], best.));
end;
```

Or just make a temporary array to have those 15 values.

```
array _n[15] _temporary_ (&n1 &n2 &n3 &n4 .... &n15);
```

which you then index into with the `I` variable.

```
... _n[i] ...
```

Comment: Yes i understand that. At first actually i programmed it without a macro just using a do loop.But it did not work . thats why i decided to go with a macro .

Comment: "At first actually i programmed it without a macro just using a do loop. But it did not work . thats why i decided to go with a macro" is a very common novice mistakes.  The journey to macro almost always requires an ability to first write working DATA or PROC step code.

Answer (score 0):

You need arrays not macros here. You're trying to use your macro variables but I would instead suggest you assign your macro variables N to an array. I would also recommend creating a single macro variable not N so you don't have to work about indexes and macro loops.

Create your N using something like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
select n into N_list_values separated by ", " from yourTable;
quit;

%put &n_list_values;
```

Then you can use it later on like this in the array.

```
array _anum{15} a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a99;
array _bnum{15} b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 b10 b11 b12 b13 b14 b99;
array astat{15} _a1 _a2 _a3 _a4 _a5 _a6 _a7 _a8 _a9 _a10 _a11 _a12 _a13 _a14 _a99;
array bstat{15} _b1 _b2 _b3 _b4 _b5 _b6 _b7 _b8 _b9 _b10 _b11 _b12 _b13 _b14 _b99;

array _n(15) _temporary_ (&N_list_values);



do i=1 to 15;
    if _anum[i] !=. then do;
    astat[i]=strip(put(_anum[i], best.))||" ("||strip(put(_anum[i]/(_n(i)) *100, 8.1))||"%)";
    end;


bstat[i] = strip(put(_bnum[i], best.));
end;
```